# Excel, VBA Vlookup, multiple returns into rows

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Very new to VBA, so please excuse my ignorance.

How would you alter the code below to return the result into rows as opposed to a string?

Thanks in advance....

data

```
Acct No   CropType
-------   ---------
0001      Grain
0001      OilSeed
0001      Hay
0002      Grain
```

function

```
=vlookupall("0001", A:A, 1, " ")
```

Here is the code:

```
Function VLookupAll(ByVal lookup_value As String, _
                   ByVal lookup_column As range, _
                   ByVal return_value_column As Long, _
                   Optional seperator As String = ", ") As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
Dim result As String

For i = 1 To lookup_column.Rows.count
   If Len(lookup_column(i, 1).text) <> 0 Then
        If lookup_column(i, 1).text = lookup_value Then
            result = result & (lookup_column(i).offset(0, return_value_column).text &     seperator)
       End If
   End If
 Next

If Len(result) <> 0 Then
result = Left(result, Len(result) - Len(seperator))
End If

VLookupAll = result
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End FunctionNotes:
```

Comment: A UDF cannot alter other cells. This will have to be rewritten as a macro, called in some other way, or as an [Array UDF](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ReturningArraysFromVBA.aspx)

Comment: As Sean Cheshire indicated, you can't return rows if you're going to call it this way as a UDF. But probably the easiest way to update your function to return rows would be to throw in a call to Split at the end. I.E. `result = Split(result, separator)`

Comment: Is your source data coming from a database or Access or another Excel workbook?  If so you can create a Data Connection, then insert it into a worksheet and it will automatically set the data up in cells and rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Function VLookupAll(ByVal lookup_value As String, _
                    ByVal lookup_column As Range, _
                    ByVal return_value_column As Long) As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i As Long, _
        j As Long
    Dim result() As Variant

    ReDim result(1 To Application.Caller.Rows.Count, 1 To 1) As Variant
    j = LBound(result)

    For i = 1 To lookup_column.Rows.Count
        If Len(lookup_column(i, 1).Text) <> 0 Then
            If lookup_column(i, 1).Text = lookup_value Then
                If j > UBound(result, 1) Then
                    Debug.Print "More rows required for output!"
                    Exit For
                End If
                result(j, 1) = lookup_column(i).Offset(0, return_value_column).Text
                j = j + 1
            End If
         End If
    Next

    VLookupAll = result
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

Now, when entering the formula on your sheet, select three cells, one above the other, then type the following:

```
=vlookupall("0001",$A:$A, 1, " ")
```

And press ctrl+shift+enter to enter the formula.

Note that if you have selected too few rows for output, your immediate window (press ctrl+g when in the vb editor) will display a message "More rows required for output!". I had this as a messagebox, but with automatic calculation on it gets a bit crazy..

Answer (score 0):

How to use above code like an array?

=VLookupAll(Main!$B$1,'Tes'!$A1:$A$1500,{1,2})