# EXCEL VBA UDF = Extract unique list in multiple output cells

Tags: excel, unique, udf

My data is as follows, lets say I name the data in named ranges as TWOCOL

```
ABC XYZ
ABC DEF
ABC FDE
ABC RST
DEF AER
DEF TRY
DEF FGR
DEF DFE
DEF SFH
DEF QWE
```

I want to write a UDF with desired output as follows:
Uniquelist(Lookup Val, Named Range)
where lookup Val can be ABC or DEF from Column 1 and named range is the full range. When lookup Val is ABC, it should return

```
XYZ
DEF
FDE
RST
```

and when Lookup Val is DEF it should return

```
AER
TRY
FGR
DFE
SFH
QWE
```

all in different cells right below where the udf is run (as a output list). Is this possible?

UDF Input Format: Uniquelist(F2,TWOCOL) where F2 will contain ABC, DEF and so on

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145011/excel-vba-vlookup-multiple-returns-into-rows is very similar and has an answer you can use.  Note if you want to do this using a UDF you must enter it as an array formula, covering as many cells as the maximum possible number of returned values.  A formula cannot populate cells where it's not present.

Comment: Thanks Tim.I was able to use this as a UDF array formula by selecting multiple cells as you suggested.